# Maxima: replace conjugate product by squared absolute value

Tags: maxima

I have an expression with several products like: a*conjugate(a).
How to ask Maxima to replace them by cabs(a)^2 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way is to switch to `polarform`. Adjust `p(e)`

```
declare([a, b, c], complex);
e: a*conjugate(a) + b^2*conjugate(b)^2 + c;
/* apply `polarform' if `p(e)' is true */
p(e):=member(e, ['a, 'b]);
polarform0(e):=if p(e) then polarform(e) else e;
scanmap(polarform0, e);
```

Ouputs:

```
c+abs(b)^4+abs(a)^2$
```

Comment: Thank you slitvinov for your aswer, it works perfectly well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not understand how it works. First, when I try: scanmap(p,e), the answer is false, which is strange. Then, assuming that p(e) is true, the function polarform0() only perform polarform on e so why directly typing polarform(e)  does not work? Sorry, for Maxima users it must be ridiculous questions but I want to understand.

Comment: Consult the documentation on `scanmap`. For example `scanmap(f, a+b);` returns `f(f(b) + f(a))`.